# What's the best practice for rendering a different GSP template based on the type of object in a collection?

Tags: templates, groovy, grails, rendering

Let's say I have a collection that is setup in my controller, named "things."  In this collection is a heterogeneous assortment of objects.  Let's say some are of type "Thing" and some others are of type "OtherThing".  In the GSP
page that renders this list, I want to render each different object type
differently.

I know that the following code works, but I can't escape the feeling that there should be a more elegant way to do this.  Does anybody have a better way?

```
        <div id="eventStream">

        <ul>
            <g:each in="${things}" var="thing">

                <g:if test="${thing.type.equals( 'Thing' )}">
                    <g:render template="/renderThing" bean="thing" />
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${thing.type.equals( 'OtherThing')}">
                    <g:render template="/renderOtherThing" bean="thing" />
                </g:if>

            </g:each>       
        </ul>

    </div>
```

(Note: there is a "type" field defined on 'Thing' and 'OtherThing' that contains those string literals.  That's just a shortcut).

EDIT:  Just realized that there's another way to do this, that depends on the notion of "convention over configuration."  I could just go with a convention that the templates are always named something like:

_renderXXXXTemplate.gsp where XXX is "Thing" or "OtherThing" or whatever.  Then I just render with something like:

```
<g:render template="/render${thing.class.name}Template" bean="thing" />
```

Anybody care to share their thoughts on the merit of that approach?

Answer (score 1):

I hate explicit type-checks.  I would probably start by creating a private tag to render this part of the page.

```
<myApp:renderThing object="${thing}" />
```

Then I would probably add an abstract method to the base class to return the template name.  Sure, it mixes presentation logic into the business classes but it will simplify maintenance considerably.

```
abstract class Thing {
    public abstract String getTemplateName();
    ...
}

public class ThingOne extends Thing {
    public String getTemplateName() { return "templateForThingOne" }
    ...
}
```

Another idea would be to derive the template name from the class name, and add a note in the base class to remind developers to create the appropriate template for any subclass.

Comment: OK, that's the other idea I had in mind as well.  And, as you mention, it has the issue of mixing things across layers.  That has a bit of a "code smell" to me, but I guess it's still cleaner than explicit type checks (which are exactly what I want to avoid).

Comment: I don't mind adding code in the models to support presentation.  Just don't add code in the models that does presentation.